# How to get message from sale post of group with facebook api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I tried to write the code  To request data field "message" from post in a group by post id. There is no data from the required fields.

URL

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/292711980883592_911761758978608?fields=message&access_token=....
```

Result:

```
{
    id: "292711980883592_911761758978608"
}
```

How to resolve it?

Comment: Sale posts data is not in the API

Comment: Is there any way to get Sale post data?

Comment: wizkid just told you that it´s not in the api